# Symfony 3.0.9 can't access getUser() from my service

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to access my user from a service in symfony 3.0.9 with the following:

in my service.yaml:

```
seal_service:
  class: FrontBundle\Service\SealService
  public: true
  arguments:
    - "@service_container"
```

and my service is like this:

```
class SealService
{
   protected $container = null;

   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
   {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function getAvailableSeals($sn = null){

    $user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->getUser();

     ...
   }
```

but I am getting the following error:
`Attempted to call an undefined method named "getUser"`

I also tried `$this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')`

if I use `$this->container->get('fos_user.security.controller')` I get `Call to protected method Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::getUser() from context 'FrontBundle\Service\SealService'`

What am I doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inject container in service:
inject token storage instead.

```
seal_service:
  class: FrontBundle\Service\SealService
  public: true
  arguments:
    - ["@security.token_storage","@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; would make sense for me if I only needed to access the user but I also need doctrine

Comment: you can inject doctrine in service. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer:

```
$tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
$user = $tokenStorage->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Anyway, avoid injecting the whole container, if you only need security context.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service